# Clearing Laravel Session value in a textfield using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to clear the values in a text field upon clicking on a cross button inside it.

**HTML MARKUP**

```
<input type="text" 
    placeholder="I want to go..." 
    class="nom-fields" 
    value="{{Session::get('place')}}" 
    name="place-city" 
    id="geocomplete">
<input type="reset" 
    id="clear-input-close" 
    class="clear-input-close" 
    value="" 
    onclick="JavaScript:eraseText();">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById('geocomplete').value = '';
}
```

If works fine if the `Session::get('place')` is empty. But if it has some value, the textfiled is getting cleared and restores the value immediately. How can I clear the value just in the textfield?

Comment: Could you try to add autocomplete="off" to the input? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion Not sure if it helps. Perhaps it's some browser plugin?

Comment: is `eraseText()` getting called?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: Yes it's getting called. I verified that by alerting a text.

Comment: @Ciccio: no it's not helping.

Comment: Can you post how Laravel is rendering `value="{{Session::get('place')}}" ` using Chrome Developer tools.

Comment: It's outputing the Session variable value. Just that.

Comment: Is your page auto refreshing or do you have some sort of auto refresh tool running in your browser? I tested your code on JSBin and it works, so something else is going on.  http://jsbin.com/qowovobepi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Even I checked it. There is no auto refreshing or any sort of such tool running. Can you try to create a Session variable in Laravel and try to clear the textfield?

Comment: Works great. When you say "But if it has some value, the textfiled is getting cleared and restores the value immediately." Do you refresh your browser? Also try a different browser and see if that helps.

Comment: `function eraseText() {
  document.getElementById('geocomplete').value = '';
  alert('cleared');
}`

I tried this code. So it clears the value, alert "cleared" and then fills up the textfield with the same value.

Comment: test this, `function eraseText() { document.getElementById('geocomplete').value = ''; 

alert(document.getElementById('geocomplete').value); }`

Comment: @whoacowboy: tested with different browsers and it's the same result.

Comment: and when you say, "I'm trying to clear the values in a text field upon clicking on a cross button inside it.", I feel you can use `<textarea>`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: the alert displays nothing, but the textfiled still displays the same value.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary: I'm trying to use text field for design reasons.

Comment: @user1012181 What you have shown us **works**. This means there is something else going on with the system that you will have to debug. You can check the network tab in your dev tools to see if you are getting more data from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel Session is handled on the server side, so you need to clear it from there. One approach would be like this.

*Note:* This uses jQuery, if you are not, hitting a url with javascript only is a little more involved. [Check out this question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery).

**AnyController.php**

```
    public function clearSessionKey($key)
    {
        if (Session::has($key))
        {
            Session::forget($key);
        }
    }
```

**Routes.php**

```
    Route::get('clear/session/{key}', 'AnyController@clearSessionKey');
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function eraseText() {
        document.getElementById('geocomplete').value = '';

        $.getJSON("/clear/session/place",
        function(data) {
            //doSomethingWith(data); 
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to clear the Session variable. I just want to clear the input field. It can be done from client side I guess.

Comment: @user1012181 Your question title is confusing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I want to go..." class="nom-fields" value="12345" name="place-city" id="geocomplete">
<input type="reset" id="clear-input-close" class="clear-input-close" value="✖" onclick="eraseText()">
<script>
    function eraseText() {
        document.getElementById('geocomplete').value = '';
    };
</script>
```

[It clears whatever is in the text field.](http://jsfiddle.net/vL4qy8rr/)

I think your problem might have been when you were loading your javascript function, or how you were using it in `onclick`.

If you right click on the page, and select `Inspect element`, there is a `console` tab that will show you javascript errors. That can give you a better idea of what specifically is going wrong.

Comment: I checked the console and there's no error. It's really frustrating :/

Comment: @user1012181 Your problem is that something is re-writing to that text field. My bet would be you are accidentally submitting a form when clicking the reset button, and reloading the page.

Comment: The page is not reloading. I'm 100% sure about it. It's all happening in a fraction of second.

Comment: @user1012181 The time in which you perceive something is a terrible metric for what's going on behind the scenes when it comes to computers.

Comment: I checked the developers tool when inspecting the reload.

Comment: Ok, cool. You should try making a simple view with just the html in my answer, and see if it works as expected. Next, make the value default to the session place value. If that works, you know something else is happening to reset that field. Check your on click bindings.